# Is there a performance decrease when using a collection as a ref with Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say you have a database, and the tree looks like this:

```json
{
  1: {
    status: 'In Progress'
  },
  2: {
    status: 'Delivered'
  },
  3: {
    status: 'In Progress'
  }
}
```

and millions of it.

I want to do something when an item gets to `Delivered` status (coming from `In Progress`), so this is what I did:

```
const ref = database.ref('deliveries').on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.val().status === 'Delivered') {
    const audio = new Audio(require('@/assets/sound.mp3'))
    audio.play()
  }
})

// later
ref.off()
```

Is there gonna be a performance problem in my website since Im referencing the whole collection? Is there a better way of doing this?

FYI: I'm using firebase database, and not firestore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
database.ref('deliveries').on(
```

This will read the entire `deliveries` node, even when you're only listening for the `child_changed` event. So if you have millions of nodes that only slowly change over time, that'll lead to reading much more data than needed.

A better model in that could would be to keep an additional property `lastUpdated` for each child node, and only listen to nodes that are changed after the moment you start listening. You'd use `child_added` for that.

Comment: Thanks for this! Now I know that even though I use `child_changed`, it's still reading the entire deliveries node.

So if I add a `lastUpdated` property to each child node, I would have a query like `database.ref('deliveries').on('child_added')`? How would that determine the newly added nodes if I'm just updating the lastUpdated property?

Comment: Almost! You'd use a query to ensure you start from the moment you're interested in, so if you want changes from now, it'd be `database.ref('deliveries').orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(Date.now()).on('child_added')`